# SSO integration using Rails for WordPress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, single-sign-on

I am building Rails Application which re-directs users to a WordPress Site. All exisiting users are in Rails Database.Now I want to use SSO from Rails App to Wordpress.

I came across this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512633/single-sign-on-wordpress-from-rails) but
I am using custom authentication method instead of devise gem as called out in the solution.

Is there any other alternate methods to solve this?